# Matrix variable is not undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm coding a maze generator using the backtracking algorithm and p5.js library, but when I was coding a loop to set random positions in the maze, I noticed an error in javascript: "***maze[(x - 2)] is undefined***", but this variable is declared! I tried to read about data structures, but I couldn't find a solution for this problem.

What is happening?

Can someone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>Maze</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 720;
var height = 400;
var x, y;
var maze = Array(39).fill(Array(71).fill(0));

function setup()
{
  createCanvas(720, 400);
}

function draw()
{
  //inicial position
  x = 1;
  y = 1;
  maze[x][y] = 1;
  //grid
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke('BLACK');
  for (x = 0; x <= 720; x += 10) line(x, 0, x, 400);
  for (y = 0; y <= 400; y += 10) line(0, y, 720, y);

  found = 0;
  do
  {
    direction = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    if (direction == 0 && (y != width - 2 && maze[x][y + 2] == 0))
    {
      x2 = x;
      y2 = y;
      y += 2;
      maze[x][y] = 1;
      maze[x][y-1] = 1;
      found = 1;
    }
      else if (direction == 1 && (x > 1 && maze[x - 2][y] == 0))
      {
        x2 = x;
        y2 = y;
        x -= 2;
        maze[x][y] = 1;
        maze[x + 1][y] = 1;
        found = 1;
      }
        else if (direction == 2 && (y > 1 && maze[x][y - 2] == 0))
        {
          x2 = x;
          y2 = y;
          y -= 2;
          maze[x][y] = 1;
          maze[x][y + 1] = 1;
          found = 1;
        }
      else if (direction == 3 && (x != height - 2 && maze[x + 2][y] == 0))
      {
        x2 = x;
        y2 = y;
        x += 2;
        maze[x][y] = 1;
        maze[x - 1][y] = 1;
        found = 1;
      }
  } while (found == 0);
  noLoop();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few issues with this code.

Lets start with why you getting that error. The issue is that you are reusing global `x` and `y` variables in `for` loop that draw lines, when the loop is done, it set these variables larger than your `maze` array.

This brings us to second issue: `maze` array is smaller than width/height of the canvas.

The code is not 100% working so I don't exactly understand what it supposed to do, but it seems `x` and `y` should not exceed width/height, however you have a condition `y != width - 2` which will be true even if `y` is bigger than `width` (btw, shouldn't it be `height` instead??)

And finally, through out the code you have multiple places with `720` and `400`, instead of using `width` and `height` variables. This is a bad practice.

```js
const width = 720;
const height = 400;
var x, y;
var maze = Array(width+1).fill(Array(height+1).fill(0));
function setup()
{
  createCanvas(width, height);
}

function draw()
{
  //inicial position
  x = 1;
  y = 1;
  maze[x][y] = 1;
  //grid
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke('BLACK');
  for (let x = 0; x <= width; x += 10) line(x, 0, x, height);
  for (let y = 0; y <= height; y += 10) line(0, y, width, y);

  found = 0;
  do
  {
    direction = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    if (direction == 0 && (y <= height - 2 && maze[x][y + 2] == 0))
    {
      x2 = x;
      y2 = y;
      y += 2;
      maze[x][y] = 1;
      maze[x][y-1] = 1;
      found = 1;
    }
      else if (direction == 1 && (x > 1 && maze[x - 2][y] == 0))
      {
        x2 = x;
        y2 = y;
        x -= 2;
        maze[x][y] = 1;
        maze[x + 1][y] = 1;
        found = 1;
      }
        else if (direction == 2 && (y > 1 && maze[x][y - 2] == 0))
        {
          x2 = x;
          y2 = y;
          y -= 2;
          maze[x][y] = 1;
          maze[x][y + 1] = 1;
          found = 1;
        }
      else if (direction == 3 && (x <= width - 2 && maze[x + 2][y] == 0))
      {
        x2 = x;
        y2 = y;
        x += 2;
        maze[x][y] = 1;
        maze[x - 1][y] = 1;
        found = 1;
      }
  } while (found == 0);
  noLoop();
}
```

```html
<script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```